# Write a .bat script create database for orientdb and run by php

Tags: batch-file, orientdb

OrientDB is using console command create DB by the way run console.bat file on "..\orientdb\bin\". However i need create a .bat separate file run like this command:

```
create database remote:localhost/test <root> <password> local graph
```

And run that .bat file by PHP

Thank for advance !

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Answer (score 1):

Based on the old documentation at https://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/ImportFromRDBMS it seem that it is possible and is similar to what i want to do as well.

console.bat database.sql

where all your sql commands are in database.sql.  The link about includes a sample for porting a full database over but don;t see why it should not work for similar scripts as well.

That said i have not tested this yet.